# how to get the loctions round me in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to retrieve locations from mysql database by distance, i need a query where i can insert a point and get the points from my database in 10 miles with respect to query time and performance 
i've this code online but it doesn't work, what do you suggest

```
set @lat= 0;
set @lon = 0;
set @dist = 10;
set @rlon1 = @lon-@dist/abs(cos(radians(@lat))*69);
set @rlon2 = @lon+@dist/abs(cos(radians(@lat))*69);
set @rlat1 = @lat-(@dist/69);
set @rlat2 = @lat+(@dist/69);
select * from points 
  where st_within(4326, envelope(linestring(point(@rlon1, @rlat1), point(@rlon2, @rlat2))))

order by st_distance(point( 0,0), 4326) limit  10;
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you have found is for PostgreSQL with the PostGIS plugin.  It will not work in MySQL.

Using PostgreSQL with the PostGIS plugin is preferred for geo-spacial queries, but if all you need is a list of coordinates within 10 miles of a given coordinate then MySQL will be fine.

Comment: how can i do it with mysql ?

Comment: It depends how accurate you want to be.  Converting distance in miles to a circle of latitude and longitude coordinates is complicated and computationally expensive.  The quickest code would calculate the maximum and minimum latitude and longitude for the bounding box in PHP and the do a simple query with less then and greater than criteria.

Comment: i'm seeking better performance, not accuracy ... so if you can help with any examples it would be great help :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the function from [this blog post](http://www.cosmocode.de/en/blog/gohr/2010-06/29-calculate-a-destination-coordinate-based-on-distance-and-bearing-in-php) you can calculate the bounding box for the search radius.  This is only approximate and will return some results which are slightly further away than the required distance.

```
$coordinate = array
    (   $latitude,
        $longitude,
    );
$distanceInKilometres = ($distanceInMiles * 1.609344);

$boundBoxTop = distanceInKilometres($coordinate, $distanceInKilometres, 0);
$boundBoxRight = distanceInKilometres($coordinate, $distanceInKilometres, 90);
$boundBoxBottom = distanceInKilometres($coordinate, $distanceInKilometres, 180);
$boundBoxLeft = distanceInKilometres($coordinate, $distanceInKilometres, 270);

$sql = '
    SELECT
        *,
        SQRT(POWER(ABS(`latitude` - '.$latitude.'), 2) + POWER(ABS(`longitude` - '.$longitude.'), 2)) AS `distance`
    FROM
        `points`
    WHERE
        `latitude` >= '.$boundBoxTopBottom[0].'
        AND `longitude` >= '.$boundBoxTopLeft[1].'
        AND `latitude` <= '.$boundBoxTopTop[0].'
        AND `longitude` <= '.$boundBoxTopRight[1].'
    ORDER BY
        `distance`
    ';

// run the query and get the results
```

Assuming you have the variables `$latitude`, `$longitude`, and `$distanceInMiles`.